# Laravel 5.7 Causing error on "selected" keyword if sent through POST only in live environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am having issue with laravel 5.7, when I try to add the below mentioned description in any of POST forms, I am getting error (whoops something went wrong) without any log trace . this error is only happening in my live server, local environment is working fine.

"The raw material for shelled cooked Chinese chestnuts is fine selected from Yanshan chestnuts."

I noticed this 'selected' keyword is causing issue, but I am unable to resolve.

PS: I am using laravel 5.7 with PHP 7.1 and MariaDB 10

I tried debugging and found out the the code control is not present in POST method handler function, so it must be causing issue with laravel Request.

I got an alternate solution to this issue that replaces 'select', 'insert', 'update' and 'delete' with some alternate keywords while sending from forms (frontend) while posting and then replacing them back with original keyword from backend (laravel).

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

The error page is also weird (not of laravel 5.7) here is the link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4YEb.jpg

**FrontEnd Code Sample**

```
{!! Form::model($company,['route' => 'member.company.store']) !!}

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    {{Form::text('name',null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Company name'])}} 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Introduction</label>
    {{Form::textarea('description',null,['placeholder' => 'Company introduction..'])}} 
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent">Update</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

**Backend Code Sample**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $uid = auth()->id();
    $company_profile = Company::where('user_id',$uid)->first();
    if($company_profile)
    {
        $company_profile->name = $request->name;
        $company_profile->description = $request->description;
        $company_profile->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `APP_DEBUG` in .env file to `true`. This will show you what is the error.

Comment: There is no error inside laravel.log

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file. Then access your page where you are getting the error. Now the error will be more readable.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, still same error, kindly check snapshot that I've attached.

PS: I tried debugging in AppServiceProvider file and I am unable to get code control in that file.

Comment: Run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` commands then load that page.

Comment: already did, there is no trace of log, no code control inside AppServiceProvider file as well

Comment: Can you provide your controller and form as well as model code?

Comment: Added coded sample in post, see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195675/discussion-between-dhananjay-kyada-and-rattlesnk).

Comment: What does this mean "code control is not present in POST"?

Comment: It means even if I enter exit(); statement in the first line of method, the execution does not stop and I still get that same whoops error. (no code control present)